# How to get the unique identifier for a city through the Google Places Autocomplete API performing the search in multiple languages​​?

Tags: json, google-places-api

I need to get a unique identifier for the name of a city when that same city is again sought in another language API to find this place same city.

Example:

I do a search via the Google API Autocomplete place like this:

> City: New York

The result is:

> New York, NY, USA Country code: U.S.

And when I do another search for "New York" in Russian, for example, I need a unique identifier for New York to know that New York is the same in English as in Russian "Нью-Йорк"

The results is:

> Нью-Йорк, Нью-Йорк, США Код страны: США

My question is how do I identify that "New York City" is the same in both searches, as I compare the results from the same city in different language and identify the two answers refer to the same New York City?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following two queries.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=newyork&types=(cities)&language=en&sensor=true&key=<YOUR-API-KEY>
```

Here are few first lines of the response in JSON. As you see there is an `id` available in the result (`reference` values are redacted):

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "New York, NY, United States",
         "id" : "7eae6a016a9c6f58e2044573fb8f14227b6e1f96",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 8,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "CkQzAAAAs[...]g5OK5Y",
         ...
```

Now the query for Russian:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Нью-Йорк&types=(cities)&language=ru&sensor=true&key=<YOUR-API-KEY>
```

This query returns few more predictions (cities with the same name in Missouri, Nebraska, etc.), but still you can find New York City from the Russian results using the `id`:

```
    {
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Нью-Йорк, Соединенные Штаты Америки",
         "id" : "7eae6a016a9c6f58e2044573fb8f14227b6e1f96",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 8,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "CmRZAAAA[...]s10LLA",
         ... 

      {
         "description" : "Нью Йорк, Миссури, Соединенные Штаты Америки",
         "id" : "211cae70217210a77581fd2a2dca45bc4286e064",
         ...
         "reference" : "CnRpAAAA[...]FUydA",
         ...
      {
         "description" : "Нью Йорк, Небраска, Соединенные Штаты Америки",
         "id" : "10a97689b3441120410e18c71d7f1b9ed70ac2e7",
         ...
         "reference" : "CnRrAAAA[...]XrkzYY",
         ...
      {
         "description" : "Нью-Йорк Милс, Нью-Йорк, Соединенные Штаты Америки",
         "id" : "2902d4dc0e1ecfe52aef4da6d5eb06e4c9fab4d9",
         ...
         "reference" : "CoQBcwAAA[...]g3G1Jw",
         ...
```

And you can query the *Place Details API* using the `reference` (which is different for each of the prediction results above):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CkRAAAAA[...]cLKfOc_4mvY&language=ru&sensor=true&key=<YOUR-API-KEY>
```

And use `id` to verify the identity of the place you are searching for. Quoting *Place Details API* [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests):

> `id` contains a unique stable identifier denoting this place. This identifier may not be used to retrieve information about this place, but can be used to consolidate data about this Place, and to **verify the identity of a Place across separate searches**. As `ids` can occasionally change, it's recommended that the stored `id` for a Place be compared with the `id` returned in later Details requests for the same Place, and updated if necessary.

Passing `id` to this query is still possible, but `reference` is a required field:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?id=7eae6a016a9c6f58e2044573fb8f14227b6e1f96&language=ru&reference=CkRAAAAA[...]cLKfOc_4mvY&sensor=true&key=<YOUR-API-KEY>
```