# Google Autocomplete language

Tags: jquery, google-places-api

I have the following situation. On a website users are submitting location of apartments based on google Autocomplete . They pick a city from google suggestion list and i take that city and country (via api) and save them to the database.

Other users may search for listings in that city using also a google Autocomplete form. The problem appears when the users are using different languages.

For ex - user 1 is in USA. When he submits his listing i receive from google the country "united states" .

When user 2 (who lives in Netherlands) search using google Autocomplete i receive the country "Verenigde Staten" (USA in duch). But the search algorithm will not function since the submitted listing is saved as "united states" and not  "Verenigde Staten".

Is there a way to show the suggestion list in user language but receive the results in English (so i can save and search using only English). Maybe translate the results ?

I know i can "block" the suggestion list in english but i would like to use this as final measure.

This is my code

```
input = (document.getElementById('property_city_front'));
defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(90, 180)
);

options = {
    bounds: defaultBounds,
    types: ['(cities)'],
};

componentForm = {
    establishment: 'long_name',
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_2: 'long_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name',
    postal_code_prefix: 'short_name',
    neighborhood: 'long_name',

};


if (document.getElementById('property_city_front')) {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        fillInAddress(place);
    });
}
```

Following the suggestion i retrive the place id(auto complete made in Dutch) and query the PlacesService but the results i got are still in Dutch and not in english.
Here is the code

```
  var request = {
        placeId: 'ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g',
        id: '7eae6a016a9c6f58e2044573fb8f14227b6e1f96',
        language:'en'
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('searchmap'), {
    zoom: 15,
    scrollwheel: false
    });

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails(request, callback);

    function callback(place, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log (place);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is most likely already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421909/how-to-get-the-unique-identifier-for-a-city-through-the-google-places-autocomple).

In short the response contains an ID which should be the same for both the queries.
You can use this id to identify what country the user is looking for.
According to the documentation:

> id contains a unique stable identifier denoting this place. This
>   identifier may not be used to retrieve information about this place,
>   but can be used to consolidate data about this Place, and to verify
>   the identity of a Place across separate searches. As ids can
>   occasionally change, it's recommended that the stored id for a Place
>   be compared with the id returned in later Details requests for the
>   same Place, and updated if necessary.

You can query the Places API using the reference. Reference is different per language. You could optional add the retrieved ID.

Comment: Hi, Sorry - i was away - i;m testing this now. Looks like the good solution.

Comment: Hi ,I'm not sure this is working -   I'm retrieving the id and place id from the original google autocomplete input in Dutch. Then i query the place service with that id and the language set to en but i still got the input in english. Posted the code as edit in the question.

Comment: If you search in Dutch and check that id it should be the same as when you type the place in English

Comment: You shouldn't use the placeId which is the id for the dutch place, if you remove that it should work i think

Comment: Yes, but that is not helping me since i have to receive the results in en when the suggestion is in dutch. I cannot change  how all the places are stored in db and use the placeid instead of place name.

Comment: placeId is required - it works without id but not without placeID. In both cases the result is in dutch.

Comment: If i'm right you'll get a reference back aswell per prediction. You need to use this prediction in combination with the Id (not placeId)
So you'll get an url like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?id=7eae6a016a9c6f58e2044573fb8f14227b6e1f96&language=ru&reference=CkRAAAAA[...]cLKfOc_4mvY&sensor=true&key=<YOUR-API-KEY>

Comment: It still doesn't work - however i will give the bounty for all your help&efforts on this matter. thanks