# How to identify a city by address in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to get a unique identifier for the city name after entering an full address using "Google Autocomplete".

I do a search via the Google API Autocomplete place like this:

> Vulytsya Tereshchenkivsʹka, 4А Kyiv, Ukraine

From the data received from Google, I get the city, and I need to write it in a separate table in the database, for further filtering by city, but the name is not an exact identifier for checking for duplicates.

Is it possible to get some unique value for the city to write to the database?

I tried:

- place_id: but he points to a place, not a city
- plus_code: the value is not always unique to the city and for some reason google does not always give it away

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the unique identifier for a city through the Google Places Autocomplete API performing the search in multiple languages​​?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421909/how-to-get-the-unique-identifier-for-a-city-through-the-google-places-autocomple)

Comment: just filter the results by adding type parameter set to cities and you will only receive cities in the result

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski This is not exactly the same question, in my case the user clogs the full address, and not just the city. And as I mentioned place_id (deprecated "id") defines a place, not a city

Comment: for results limited by types=cities place_id is equivalent to a city

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski I understand it. But I need the full address for another table in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the unique identifier (**Place ID**) of a city component from a Places API Autocomplete search result of a full address like "Vulytsya Tereshchenkivsʹka, 4А Kyiv, Ukraine", currently you'll have to make an additional request to get the place id of that specific component.

If you have the coordinates, you can try using [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-restricted) for the given coordinates (50.444265,30.514581) and filtered by `locality` type. You should get the address below:

```
Address: Kyiv, Ukraine, 02000
Location: 50.4501,30.5234
Place ID: ChIJBUVa4U7P1EAR_kYBF9IxSXY
```

Here's a sample request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=50.444265,30.514581&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Lastly, since address components in Places API search results does not currently have the place IDs for each individual component, there is a Feature request in the Google Public Issue tracker for this -- Add place_id in each address_components: 
 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827596

I'd recommend you to star it to receive updates.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank. That is what I was looking for. It is a pity that there is no normal way to get the place_id of the city.
Made a small [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c1urhavo/1/) if someone would be interested